# to_csv in pandas // bad output of string column which is like int column

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

I have in dataframe an id column

```
id
 5951745582078997487951745608975661464
 5951399837313377876951400233463338261
 595101539674361970769510153967984467076
 795z13nglozjziiinrva235jhb4ulfzexehw04
 795z13tdlqpgkqvtv0ur23gxzqpltf4e5fsx
```

but when I' using

```
df.to_csv('df.csv')
```

something happens and it convert it to int and the csv file shows the column like [pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPWBu.png)

the dtype of id is object and I even try to make

```
df['id']=df.id.apply(lambda x: str(x))
```

I don't want to enter a space to all values.

Edit: like Ted Petrou said the problem is Excel conversions so basically no problem, thanks

Comment: Do you need `df['id']=df.id.astype(str)` ?

Comment: This looks like it might be a microsoft excel issue as some of the values in the above column are all numeric. Try and convert the column type in excel.

Comment: yes! you right, I didn't think of open it with notepad